# summarizing a list of lists in python and make a new matrix

Tags: python

I have a list of lists like this small example:

```
[['chr19', '35789598', '35789629', '21', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000'], ['chr19', '35789598', '35789629', '24', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000'], ['chr19', '35789598', '35789629', '52', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000'], ['chr19', '35789598', '35789629', '88', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000'], ['chr19', '35798974', '35799005', '56', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000'], ['chr19', '35883830', '35883861', '16', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000'], ['chr19', '35884320', '35884351', '51', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000']]
```

as you see every inner list has 7 elements. I want to make a new list of lists in which there is no inner list with similar 1st, 2nd and 3rd elements. in fact if there are some inner lists in which 1st, 2nd and 3rd elements are similar, I would take only the 1st inner list and remove the other inner lists.expected output for the small example would look like this:

expected output:

```
[['chr19', '35789598', '35789629', '21', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000'], ['chr19', '35798974', '35799005', '56', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000'], ['chr19', '35883830', '35883861', '16', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000'], ['chr19', '35884320', '35884351', '51', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000']]
```

here is the code in python which does not return what I expect:

```
result = []
for i in mat:
    for j in i:
        if j == j-1:
            result.append(j)
```

Comment: You should include your actual expected output as well

Comment: Numpy matrix? Or simply nested lists?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['chr19', '35789598', '35789629', '21', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000'], 
        ['chr19', '35789598', '35789629', '24', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000'],
        ['chr19', '35789598', '35789629', '52', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000'], 
        ['chr19', '35789598', '35789629', '88', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000'], 
        ['chr19', '35798974', '35799005', '56', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000'], 
        ['chr19', '35883830', '35883861', '16', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000'], 
        ['chr19', '35884320', '35884351', '51', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000']]
# Convert your list of list to a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
       0         1         2   3      4         5         6
0  chr19  35789598  35789629  21  chr19  35510000  36200000
1  chr19  35789598  35789629  24  chr19  35510000  36200000
2  chr19  35789598  35789629  52  chr19  35510000  36200000
3  chr19  35789598  35789629  88  chr19  35510000  36200000
4  chr19  35798974  35799005  56  chr19  35510000  36200000
5  chr19  35883830  35883861  16  chr19  35510000  36200000
6  chr19  35884320  35884351  51  chr19  35510000  36200000

df = df.drop_duplicates([0, 1, 2], keep='first')
       0         1         2   3      4         5         6
0  chr19  35789598  35789629  21  chr19  35510000  36200000
4  chr19  35798974  35799005  56  chr19  35510000  36200000
5  chr19  35883830  35883861  16  chr19  35510000  36200000
6  chr19  35884320  35884351  51  chr19  35510000  36200000

# If you need the data as the list of lists still output like this:
output = df.values
array([['chr19', '35789598', '35789629', '21', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000'],
       ['chr19', '35798974', '35799005', '56', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000'],
       ['chr19', '35883830', '35883861', '16', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000'],
       ['chr19', '35884320', '35884351', '51', 'chr19', '35510000', '36200000']], 
       dtype=object)

# Otherwise you can continue to use the DataFrame for your analysis
```